# Calculate A-Weighting and C-weighting values

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio

I am working on fetching the current peak and average peak values using Core Audio, however I would also like to fetch A-Weighted, Flat, and C-Weighted dB values. I've searched the documentation, but failed to find anything on this concept.

Comment: And where would you like to get the values from? what data do you have? You need to explain your problem more if you want people to be able to help you

Comment: Sorry for the above post made, I have been using core audio framework to show the peak and average peak values however i would now want to show Flat, A Weighting, C Weighting values in that. I am new to this site, so let me know if you need more clarification on this.

Comment: You should be able to "edit" your original post and provide the extra information. It will improved your chances of getting an answer. Please keep in mind though that your question is not a very common subject, so you may have to wait a while until someone who is familiar with what you are trying to do is around. Try to remember, that the more information you provide the better, especially when the subject is not common, as most people will only take one look at a question - and if it is not well written they wont come back, and you may have missed your chance by then

Answer (score 1):

CoreAudio does not provide such options. You can [filter the signal](http://www.webcitation.org/5xZXWNqVh), then calculate the peak/avg from the filtered signal.

Comment: Thanks Justin, but how do i calculate the 'f' or 's' values to substitute in the formula? Can you please help me with some code?

Comment: @Nitu GIYF :) http://users.skynet.be/solaris/linuxaudio/getit.html - direct: http://users.skynet.be/solaris/linuxaudio/downloads/aweight.tar.bz2

Comment: Thanks Justin, will get back to you incase of any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (full- or third-) octave band filters and use tabulated values to perform the A- or C- weighting for each band. Calculate the signal level in each band and add the tabulated weighting values found [here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-dba-spl.htm).